# How to place tags around everything that isn't already located inside <div> tags?

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
This is a <div class="animal">fish</div>. He likes to <div class="verb">swim</div>.
This is a <div class="animal">bear</div>.
The <div class="animal">bear</div> likes <br> to eat fish.
```

I need to place tags around all of the text, including punctuation, that aren't already inside any `<div>` tags. E.g.:

```
<div class="other">This is a </div><div class="animal">fish</div><div class="other">. He likes to </div><div class="verb">swim</div><div class="other">.</div>
<div class="other">This is a </div><div class="animal">bear</div><div class="other">.</div>
<div class="other">The </div><div class="animal">bear</div><div class="other"> likes <br> to eat fish.</div>
```

- Multiple and nested `<div>`'s might appear on the same line.
- `<div>`'s never span across multiple lines.

How can I mark `<div class="other">` and `</div>` around all unmarked portions of text in a file?

Comment: This kind of screams [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '!/^</ {$0="<div class=\"other\">"$0"</div>"}1'
<div class="other">This is a <div class="animal">fish</div>. He likes to <div class="verb">swim</div>.</div>
<div class="other">This is a <div class="animal">bear</div>.</div>
<div class="other">The <div class="animal">bear</div> likes <br> to eat fish.</div>
```

It just wrap `<div.. /div>` around every line not starting with a `<`

Comment: I've already tried putting everything inside `<divs>`, but since the CSS code defining what the class does treats each part somewhat like a "box", this solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl you can `split` on the `<div>` elements and capture them at the same time. The result is this list

- `This is a`
- `<div class="animal">fish</div>`
- `. He likes to`
- `<div class="verb">swim</div>`
- `.
  This is a`
- `<div class="animal">bear</div>`
- `.
  The`
- `<div class="animal">bear</div>`
- `likes <br> to eat fish.`

Then all that is necessary is to bracket in a `<div>` those elements of the list that don't already have one and rejoin the parts.

This program demonstrates, although it produces some nasty HTML!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = <<'__END_TEXT__';
This is a <div class="animal">fish</div>. He likes to <div class="verb">swim</div>.
This is a <div class="animal">bear</div>.
The <div class="animal">bear</div> likes <br> to eat fish.
__END_TEXT__

my @parts = split m{(<div\b.+?</div>)}, $text;

print "- `$_`\n" for @parts;

for my $part (@parts) {
  $part = qq{<div class="other">$part</div>} unless $part =~ m{^<div\b};
}

my $fixed_text = join '', @parts;
print $fixed_text, "\n";
```

**output**

```
<div class="other">This is a </div><div class="animal">fish</div><div class="other">. He likes to </div><div class="verb">swim</div><div class="other">.
This is a </div><div class="animal">bear</div><div class="other">.
The </div><div class="animal">bear</div><div class="other"> likes <br> to eat fish.
</div>
```

Comment: @lihao: It won't. However if the data to be processed includes anything more complex than the example shown in the question then a regex solution isn't appropriate

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/\n/!{s/<div/\n&/g;s/\/div>/&\n/g};/^<div/!{s/^/<div class="other">/;s/\n\|$/<\/div>&/};P;D' file
```

This will split the line into a series of statements.